# jQuery margin left depending on element width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to apply a css style using jquery to an element that has a fixed width.

I want to make it´s margin-left be (minus) the width of the element divide by two.

How can I do that?

this is the css:

```
.top_middle{
    width: 33%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 49%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I tried with something like this but it doesn´t work:

```
    var width = $('.top_middle').width()

    $('.top_middle').css(function(){
        'margin-left' : - "width" / 2
    })
```

Comment: What does your div element & css look like ie top_middle

Comment: I edit it, sorry the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function you have width in "" marks which means it will be run as a string not pick up the variable try

Edit: Your function seems wrong for the jquery syntax try

```
    var width = $('.top_middle').width() / 2;
$('.top_middle').css('margin-left',-width);
```

See example here http://jsfiddle.net/domjgreen/ydEwx/2/

Comment: Dominic, is it possible to get the margin left with the percentage? I´m trying to make it responsive and it adds the margin in pixel, not %

Comment: @fxg Append the percentage symbol to the end, e.g.: `-width+'%'`

Comment: @fxg If the width of your div is fixed to 33%, then try this to make it responsive `$('.top_middle').css("margin-left", (-33/2) + "%");`. Or you can do this with CSS3 if you are cool with that `margin-left: calc(33% / 2 * -1);`

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are trying to divide the string "width" by 2, which is not what you want. You want to divide the variable width by 2, like this:

```
$('.top_middle').css({
    marginLeft : - (width / 2) + 'px'
});
```

Also you're passing a function to css(), you should pass an object or a pair of arguments corresponding to a css property and the value you want to set for it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var halfwidth = $('.top_middle').width()/2;
$('.top_middle').css({'margin-left' : "-" + halfwidth });
```